# how to refresh a 'div' anytime an element in the page is clicked - jquery

Tags: jquery, publish-subscribe

i wanted to reload an element whenever there is a click event on any form element. can anyone help me with the jquery syntax?
something like

`function addClickHandlers() {
    $.publish('refreshDiv');
   }`

where the div's reloadTopic is set to refreshDiv

thanks

Comment: what do you understand by reload? should new html data be inserted ? should a layout be removed, added ? ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click events bubble up, so you can just set the event on the form element:

```
$('#myForm').click(function () {
    $.publish('refreshDiv'); 
});
```

You could also use `.delegate()` to only catch clicks from certain elements within the form:

```
$('#myForm').delegate("input, select, textarea", "click", function () {
    $.publish('refreshDiv'); 
});
```

Comment: what if there are many forms that contain this specific div and i want it to reload whenever something is clicked in any one of the forms? this of course will mean that i have some file that is included in all these pages and this script goes in that file

Comment: I don't see any `publish` method in jQuery, it that a plugin or what?

Comment: @sAc: I assume it is, there's not really enough detail in the question to tell otherwise.

Comment: @abs: replace `$('#myForm')` with a more suitable selector, e.g. `$('form');`, which will target all forms.

Comment: i think i will just use a timer to publish it - doesnt seem to be working for elements inside the form

thanks Andy E

Answer (score 0):

Add a handler to every element.

```
$('*').click(function () {
    $.publish('refreshDiv'); 
    return false; // to stop it from bubbling as we already handled it here.
});
```

Comment: using the universal selector `*` in is bad karma and the spirit of john resig might come and get you if you do so!

Comment: It's also very inefficient to apply click handlers to *every* element in the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I can interpret your text in two ways:

1) execute `$.publish` on any element which is a children of a form element

```
$('form').children().click(function(){
   $.publish('refreshDiv');
});
```

2) execute `$.publish` on all `form elements` (like `checkboxes, radio buttons, etc.`)

```
$('form').find('input').click(function(){
   $.publish('refreshDiv');
});
```

Like Andy E. suggested, it has a better performance to `delegate` the click event, so less `event handlers` are bound.

3)

```
$('form').delegate('input', 'click', function(){
   $.publish('refreshDiv');
});
```

Comment: You can use *delegate()* for a more efficient `2)`.

Answer (score 0):

I dont have idea about publish and i never seen this kind of code in jquery but if u want to reload whole page then u can do follow thing

```
<button id="PageRefresh">Refresh a Page in jQuery</button>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $('#PageRefresh').click(function() {

              location.reload();

    });

</script>
```

and if u want reload particular div then i think u should use ajax in jquery and reload the html in div.

```
$.post("/page", frm.serialize(), function(data) {
                    $("#ReminderProjectCount").html(data);
            });
```